# c++ move semantics and pass by value

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I am implementing some container, e.g. binary search tree, and I want to insert something. The container has a root pointer to a node struct with an addnode function.

```
<typename T>
void container::insert (T val){
    n = new node(std::move(val))
    root->addnode(n);
}
```

Now a simple node constructor may look something like this:

```
node(T val): value(std::move(item)) {}
```

My question is: are the `std::move` in both the constructor of node and in insert function necessary to efficiently move rvalues, and why?

Comment: Any named variable is lvalue regardless of a passed value, copy, by reference or by rvalue reference, thus std::move is necessary.

Comment: I'd ask myself what happens if `T` can't be moved (efficiently)